# JavaFX Playing AudioClip,InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, invocationtargetexception

I am trying to play mp3 file and getting an exception. Here is my code and stack trace. My sound is in my workspace.

```
public class Main extends Application {
//my code
    @Override 
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        URL resource = getClass().getResource("/Alistirma/src/IkinciAlistirma/hated.mp3"); //its in my workspace
        AudioClip clip = new AudioClip(resource.toString()); //line 21

        final Button button = new Button("Play"); //simple button just for playing clip
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                clip.play();
            }
        });
               //after here nothing important for my problem.
               //basic FX stuff
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is just simple code for playing mp3 however i get an exception, Here is stack trace

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at IkinciAlistirma.Main.start(Main.java:21)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application IkinciAlistirma.Main
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
URL resource = URL resource = getClass().getResource("/Alistirma/src/IkinciAlistirma/hated.mp3");
```

First : Your mp3 file is not reachable from your workspace with `getResource(String path)` method. Depending on your environment and IDE, it will sarch for "Alistirma/src/IkinciAlistirma/hated.mp3" in different place in your project. You can find the start point folder where the `getResource(String path)` is searching for your resource by printing the URL given by `getResource(".")` and then deduct where you want to put your file. If you want to keep your file where it is, you still can reach it with the `File` class.

Second : why `URL resource = URL resource =` ? copy/paste fail I suppose ;) ?

Comment: When I was creating this question I changed something and copied from my code I didnt see that part thanks. ^^

Comment: Ok, thanks I just fixed it thanks to Kwoinkwoin. Looking for getResource(".") worked. I was targeting src folder but default target was bin folder.